# JDA - некорректный список пользователей

Tags: java, discord, discord-api, discord-jda

Я создаю Discord бота и столкнулся со странной проблемой. Нужно пройтись по каждому пользователю на сервере и выполнить условное действие. Но при получении списка всех участников, в нем есть только я и сам бот.

```
public class Bot extends ListenerAdapter {
    public void onGuildMessageReceived(GuildMessageReceivedEvent Event) {
        String Message = Event.getMessage().getContentRaw();

        if(Message.charAt(0) == Globals.BOT_PREFIX) {
            String[] Args = Message.split("\\s+");

        if(Args[0].equalsIgnoreCase(CommandType.COMMAND_DEV_TEST)) {
            List<Member> MemberList = Event.getGuild().getMembers();
            for(int i = 0; i < MemberList.size(); i++)
                System.out.println(MemberList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Даже если пишет другой человек, то все равно отображаюсь только я и бот.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61226721/discord-jda-invalid-member-list/61229594#61229594

При использовании JDA выше 4.1.1, необходимо во время инициализации бота использовать:

```
JDABuilder.createDefault(token)
      .setChunkingFilter(ChunkingFilter.ALL) // enable member chunking for all guilds
      .setMemberCachePolicy(MemberCachePolicy.ALL) // ignored if chunking enabled
      .enableIntents(GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS)
      .build();
```